# How to convert numpy.ndarray image to discord.File?

Tags: python, discord.py, numpy-ndarray

I found similar question but about PIL: [How can I upload a PIL Image object to a Discord chat without saving the image?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59868527/how-can-i-upload-a-pil-image-object-to-a-discord-chat-without-saving-the-image), and using it results in
AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'save'
which is surely because I use OpenCV and not PIL.

The question is how to convert this numpy.ndarray to discord.File (using binary or otherwise)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case anybody also get this problem here is function that takes cv2 image(which is basically numpy.ndarray) and returns discord.File:

```
def cv2discordfile(img):
    img_encode = cv2.imencode('.png', img)[1]
    data_encode = np.array(img_encode)
    byte_encode = data_encode.tobytes()
    byteImage = BytesIO(byte_encode)
    image=discord.File(byteImage, filename='image.png')
    return image
```