# Can a discord bot send a message with an image it got via a direct message?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, bots

I'm working on a Discord bot that handles taking direct messages and posting the message to a Channel in a Discord server i'm in. This is working as intended but i was wondering if there is any way to send images it gets via direct messages as well?

I'm using Python to code my bot

```
# Post the message into the channel
    await server_channel.send(f'**Complaint about the following**\n{message.content}')
```

At the moment it can only output text, when an image is sent the{message.content} returns as blank

I don't even know where to start. The bot is currently able to post the Direct Message(DM) Contents in a Specific Channel and reply to the DM confirming its been posted.

EDIT:
I have been able to sort this out with the following code

```
# Get the server channel you want to send the message to
        server_channel = client.get_channel(int(CHANNEL_ID))

if message.attachments:
            # Get the image file
            image_file = message.attachments[0]

            # Read the image file content as bytes
            image_bytes = await image_file.read()

            # Send the image to the server channel
            await server_channel.send(file=discord.File(fp=BytesIO(image_bytes), filename=image_file.filename))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`discord.Message.attachments`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=attachments#discord.Message.attachments), it returns a list of attachments, you can loop through and get [`discord.Attachment`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=attachments#discord.Attachment) attributes (like the URL). After that you can simply send URL as the content, or you can send [`discord.File`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=discord%20file#discord.File) using **Requests** and **PIL** : [Here is an example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59868527/how-can-i-upload-a-pil-image-object-to-a-discord-chat-without-saving-the-image).